# Saving to CoreData while app is in background or foreground

Tags: swift, multithreading, core-data, healthkit

I've got a HKObserverQuery that triggers successfully when my app is in the background while monitoring for new workouts. However it is the subsequently triggered function that updates and saves the CoreData view context that is creating issues.

All functions, including the HKObserverQuery and CoreData CRUD function run from an observable object view model, using a single NSManagedObjectContext passed in to the view model.

The view context saves while running in the background, but when running in the foreground I get this error:

> Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.

When saving as such:

```
if self.viewContext.hasChanges {
     do {
         try self.viewContext.save()
     } catch {
         print(error)
     }
}
```

If I move the saving of the view context to the main thread using DispatchQueue.main.async, then the save won't function while the app is in the background (recommencing once the app enters the foreground), but silences this warning.

Using @MainActor creates the same issues when functioning in the background vs the foreground.

My understanding of threads/queues is limited. Short of creating 2 separate functions, one for background and one for foreground, is there a way to dynamically use the correct thread/queue?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ScenePhase` for this.

I would add this to the App struct or where ever you initialize your viewmodel.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scenephase)

```
@Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase 
@StateObject var viewmodel = Viewmodel()

var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        TestView()
            .onChange(of: scenePhase) { newValue in // observe changes to the scenephase
                viewmodel.scenePhase = newValue // and pass those changes on
            }
            
    }
}


class Viewmodel: ObservableObject{
    var scenePhase: ScenePhase = .active
    
    private func executeSave(){
        do {
            try self.viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    
    func saveContext(){
        if self.viewContext.hasChanges {
            if scenePhase == .active{ // and check for beeing in foreground
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.executeSave()
                }
            }else {
                executeSave()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Thread 25: Fatal error: Can only invoke this method on the main queue`

Produces this fatal error. I can only assume its because the observer query runs both when the app is in the foreground and background. I think I will have to separate the methods from the observer query and the other in app uses.